# Fetch Api Call to a External Api results in CORS Error, But in Browser it works fine

Tags: javascript, json, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to make a fetch call to a web server via apis.

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(
  "https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=3",
  requestOptions
)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

This seems to throw  this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABz4R.png)

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=3' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

But the same url if I try to access in the browser . Displays the data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xEcG.png)
Any help on how I can get the fetch api call to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change the code that runs the server on api-mainnet.magiceden.dev to handle CORS requests and reply with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: I am making a call to an external web server. the above code is a code snipper from thier dcumentation

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have the same problem too. It seems all magiceden apis are not allowed to be called from different domain. It works in browser because the call is from same domain.
It the cors problem is a real problem that means nobody outside of Magiceden is using these apis, which surprized me!

Answer (score 0):

What Are your "requestOptions"? I've tried this, and it's working fine.

```
fetch("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=3" )
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

Comment: This is the request Option
```var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};
```
These are directly from the api documentation. I did try the above code , Unfortunately the error repeats.